# add a tuple to a tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple:

```
a = (1,2,3)
```

and I need to add a tuple at the end

```
b = (4,5)
```

The result should be:

```
(1,2,3,(4,5))
```

Even if I wrap b in extra parents:
a + (b), I get (1,2,3,4,5) which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Remember, the comma inside the brackets is very important, like in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21857134/1903116), it should have been `a + (b,)`. Otherwise Python will consider `(b)` as simply `b` wrapped in brackets. The comma makes it a tuple.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do `a + b` you are simply concatenating both the tuples. Here, you want the entire tuple to be a part of another tuple. So, we wrap that inside another tuple.

```
a, b = (1, 2, 3), (4,5)
print a + (b,)  # (1, 2, 3, (4, 5))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> b = (4,5)
>>> a + (b,)
(1, 2, 3, (4, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

`tuple` objects are immutable. The result you're getting is a result of the fact that the `+` (and `+=`) operator is overridden to allow "extending" tuples the same way as `lists`. So when you add two tuples, Python assumes that you want to concatenate their *contents*.

To add an entire tuple onto the end of another tuple, wrap the tuple to be added inside another tuple.

```
c = a + (b,) # Add a 1-tuple containing the tuple to be added.
print(c) # >>> (1, 2, 3, (4, 5))
```